# NPM so slow, even Npm -v take 30sec

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, npm

I created a server EC2 at aws, everything was just fine, but I needed to create another instance of this image, and this one is so slow to run npm commands.
Even a npm -v command take soo long,

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-27-240:/var/www/html/api/public$ time npm -v
6.14.4

real    0m23.835s
user    0m9.961s
sys     0m0.421s
```

Although node -v is normal

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-27-240:/var/www/html/api/public$ time node -v
v10.19.0

real    0m0.161s
user    0m0.080s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I need to execute some direct functions, I tried directly with run-func (installed by npm) and this one is slow too..

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-27-240:/var/www/html/api/public$ time run-func
File name not provided i.e. run-func ./index.js

real    0m17.109s
user    0m7.158s
sys     0m0.366s
```

Really appreciate your help, any thoughts?

Comment: Let me guess: `t2.micro`? Do you have any CPU credits left?

Comment: Yes, its a t2.micro, but I have credits and if I restart the instance the npm back to normal, after 1 day it starts to become slower again, but restart change the IP and its a headache to my purpose..

Comment: Run `top` and look at your available memory, particularly the size of the buffer cache. Things that become slower over time usually indicate memory pressure, and EC2 instances don't (by default) have swap enabled. So it's possible that you're using all available memory for whatever you're running, and the only thing that the system can do to make room is discard pages that belong to executable programs. This will then mean many page faults whenever you start a program that actually does something.

Comment: Sometimes, filling up memory is a bug: you hold onto data longer than you should. But in my experience it's more often an indication that you've undersized your machine for the workload that you're trying to run.

Comment: You could also try enabling swap, which will allow the system to write unused _data_ pages to disk. But that can cause its own problems, since data pages don't usually remain unused for long.